# How to SQL query on column, group-special which must belongs value ('ve02','ve14;,'ve22' ) group2-common which having rest of values

Tags: sql

SQL query for two group on one column, group 1 called special which must belongs values like ('ve02','ve14;,'ve22' ) group2 called common which having rest of values.

```
column 1
ve01
ve02
ve10
ve10
ve22

ANS:   Special | Common
        've02' | 've01'
        've22' |'ve10'
```

Comment: How do you match special and common values? E.g.: why is ve02 in the same result row as ve01?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems quite artificial, but here's a query that would do:

```
with
s as (
  select 've02' as v 
  union all select 've14'
  union all select 've2'  
),
l as (
  select s.v
  from t
  join s on t.col1 = s.v
),
ln as (
  select v, row_number() over(order by v) as n from l
),
r as (
  select s.v
  from t
  left join s on t.col1 = s.v
  where s.v is null
),
rn as (
  select v, row_number() over(order by v) as n from r
)
select lx.v as special, rx.v as common
from lx
full outer join rx on ln.n = rn.n
```